# Don't succeed running a react native app from Xcode (running the same app from cli work just fine)

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, mobile

When I try to run the app on a real device or emulator (running from Xcode) I get stuck on splash screen and able to see 'Loading dependency graph'

However, if run it from command line like `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 8"` everything works just fine and I have no problems.

What might cause the problem? Thanks

Comment: I have tried to clean up the build folder, it didn't make much difference

Answer (score 0):

try starting the bundler in a separate terminal window, e.g., `npm start -- --reset-cache` and then run Xcode.

Comment: does the bundler not finish?  It should say `Loading dependency graph, done.` when ready

Comment: it does, but nothing happens whatsoever even if I wait for decent amount of time.
When I run it from the cli I see bundles loading up from emulator (after `Loading dependency graph`). But running from Xcode just makes the terminal hang up.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem this morning, but it only affected my real device.  It was because the phone was on a different wifi network than the mac.

Comment: Try running `http://localhost:8081/status`  in a browser.  this should return `packager-status:running`.  If that works, try replacing `localhost` with the ip address of your machine (which you can find in network settings)

Comment: Both `localhost:8081/status` and `*my_ip*:8081/status` work like a charm and return `packager-status:running`

Comment: is that something that indicates that there is a possible solution?

Comment: Well, I debugged this morning by setting a breakpoint in `sourceURLForBridge` in `AppDelegate` and jumping into `RCTBundleURLProvider` to see what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

*OH MY GOD*

Being a deep js believer, I actually had never used Xcode and furthermore had never put any effort towards debugging.

Turns out, I accidentally put a breakpoint somewhere in `main.m` that has been causing the issue. I didn't notice it and now everything works just fine when I removed it.